# duplicate value in child nodes in tree view c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, treeview

I am using a treeview linked to SQL server. I have two tables area and street where area have many streets. Am populating my treeview having in each area only the streets related to that area. Am getting the streets to the 1st area and the second area node is having its streets plus the streets of the 1st area node an so on, i need to eliminate the extra streets.
Here's my code:

```
private void PopulateTreeview1()
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();

            SqlCommand cmd1 = cnn.CreateCommand();
            cmd1.CommandText = "select areaId,areaName from area";
            SqlDataAdapter sdr1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.Connection = cnn;
            sdr1.Fill(dt);


            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                // Current areaId and areaname is stored
                string areaID = dt.Rows[i]["areaId"].ToString();
                string areaName = dt.Rows[i]["areaName"].ToString();

                TreeNode AreaNode = new TreeNode(areaName);


                SqlCommand cmd2 = cnn.CreateCommand();
                cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT streetId, streetName FROM street WHERE areaId = @areaId";
                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@areaId", areaID);
                SqlDataAdapter sdr2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                cmd2.Connection = cnn;
                sdr2.Fill(dt2);

                for (int j = 0; j < dt2.Rows.Count; j++)
                {

                    // Current StreetName and StreetId is stored
                    string streetId = dt2.Rows[j]["streetId"].ToString();
                    string streetName = dt2.Rows[j]["streetName"].ToString();
                    // A TreeNode is created with current StreetName 
                    TreeNode StreetNode = new TreeNode(streetName);
                    // Current StreetNode is added as child node of AreaNode
                    AreaNode.Nodes.Add(StreetNode);
                     }

                treeView1.Nodes.Add(AreaNode);

            }

        }
```

please i need help.

Comment: As I consider, you can make one sql query using JOIN `select areaId, areaName, streetName, streetId from area join street On area.areaId == street.areaId` And then populate the grid based on a result of the query.

Comment: sorry but can u explain more where shall i use this query am newbie to c#

Comment: i need to fix it with my example because i need to add more child nodes with the same state please anybody help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my solution , i insert dt2.Clear() in between,its working right

```
cmd2.Connection = cnn;
                dt2.Clear();
                sdr2.Fill(dt2);
```